# How is ShowVirtualKeyboard run on the Delphi FireMonkey Android platform?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6, virtual-keyboard

Consider:

```
Uses FMX.VirtualKeyboard, FMX.Platform;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var Keyboard: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
    begin
        keyboard := TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService) as IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
        if  TVirtualKeyboardState.Visible in keyboard.VirtualKeyBoardState then
        begin
            Keyboard.HideVirtualKeyboard;
        end;
    end;
```

HideVirtualKeyboard is running with this code, but how is ShowVirtualKeyboard run on the [Delphi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi) [FireMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FireMonkey) Android platform?

Because for the same code, ShowVirtualKeyboard is giving:

> not enough actual parameters error in code page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ShowVirtualKeyboard`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.VirtualKeyboard.IFMXVirtualKeyboardService.ShowVirtualKeyboard) method expects to receive one parameter indicating which control the keyboard will type into. For example, to show the keyboard for typing into a memo control:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  keyboard := TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService) as IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
  keyboard.showVirtualKeyboard(memo1);
end;
```