# Keep virtual keyboard shown going from one edit to another

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

It seems the default behavior of FMX Android is that on clicking one edit and then another edit the virtual keyboard reopens.

After clicking the first edit the virtual keyboard is already shown so is there a way to keep the virtual keyboard open without the transition?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28707805/9098350) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27408727/9098350) I expected I could set

```
VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.Never;
```

And then manually show the keyboard like this

```
procedure TForm8.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  keyboard: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin
  keyboard := TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService) as IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
  keyboard.showVirtualKeyboard(Edit2);
end;
```

Allowing me to keep the keyboard open. This does put focus on `Edit2`, but it doesn't show the virtual keyboard.

The [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.VirtualKeyboard.IFMXVirtualKeyboardService.ShowVirtualKeyboard) says

> If the on-screen virtual keyboard is shown, ShowVirtualKeyboard returns True, otherwise it returns False.

And indeed `keyboard.showVirtualKeyboard(Edit2);` return `False`.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bug. I've tried to work out how to fix it, but gave up. There's a report for it, here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-34442

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the **ControlType** property to '**Platform**' for ***ALL***  Edit controls on the form. It worked for me.

Comment: It works, but on my Samsung A13 (32 bit) the "automatic compilation" choice appears every time I try to write